# Getting error while Using ONLYOFFICE with React.js

Tags: reactjs, web-crawler, onlyoffice

[i'm using onlyOffice to render with web while i'm hiting the right documentServerUrl getting error (Error load DocsAPI from http://confidential.com/example/) and but i don't no why it is crawing on http://confidential.com/example/web-apps/apps/api/documents/api.js. and giving me 404 error i'm using react for the frontend side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/852Ek.png) `

```
`import { DocumentEditor } from "@onlyoffice/document-editor-react";
import React from "react";

function DocumentViewer() {
  const onDocumentReady = () => {
    console.log("Document is ready to view");
  };

  const onLoadComponentError = function (errorCode, errorDescription) {
    switch (errorCode) {
      case -1: // Unknown error loading component
        console.log(errorDescription);
        break;

      case -2: // Error load DocsAPI from http://documentserver/
        console.log(errorDescription);
        break;

      case -3: // DocsAPI is not defined
        console.log(errorDescription);
        break;
    }
  };
  debugger;
  return (
    <>
      <DocumentEditor
        id="docxEditor"
        documentServerUrl="http://confidential.com/example/"
        config={{
          document: {
            fileType: "pdf",
            key: "my_only_office_jwt_secret",
            title:
              "Screenshot and Functionalities od e-Tappal and e-File(SRS).pdf",
            url: "http://122.176.109.190:8080/server/api/core/bitstreams/10e76505-5ebb-4812-933d-36ddf82798b0/content",
          },
          documentType: "word",
          editorConfig: {
            callbackUrl: "http://localhost:3000/",
          },
        }}
        events_onDocumentReady={onDocumentReady}
        onLoadComponentError={onLoadComponentError}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default DocumentViewer;
```

`

Comment: please do not post images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the link to your document server installed without '/example' part at the end. The '/example' is the example service of the Document Server which exists merely to check the operation of the Document Server and it shouldn't be used here. Thus, if you have your Document Server available at `https://documentserver.com` - this is the address you need to define in `documentServerUrl` as per [this reference](https://api.onlyoffice.com/editors/react#documentServerUrl).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).